# Distribution of random vectors.

Tags: probability, random-variables

If the random vectors $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ have the same joint distribution, what can you say about the distribution of $X$ and $Y$. Do $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{P}(X\in A) = \mathbb{P}((X,Y) \in A\times\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: So then $\mathbb{P}((Y,X)\in A\times\mathbb{R})$, and from there $\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in A\times A)$ so $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. Is that correct?

Comment: Your conclusion is correct but the second step isn't. You can just go backwards again: $\mathbb{P}((Y,X)\in A\times\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{P}(Y\in A)$ and then make the conclusion.